# MSDN Conflicting statement- Which protocol support which security in WCF (Particularly Transport and Message security)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Statement 1: Transport security is available on all of the bindings except for wsDualHttpBinding.

Statement 2: Transport security is available on all of the bindings except for netNamedPipeBinding.

I am a beginner, I was looking for which protocols support transport security and which protocols support message security and which support both. I came across the statements above from MSDN which I don't understand as it appears to be conflicting, which is on the same page of MSDN (below ref)

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx

Could someone please help me understand this, it will surely help many people like me. I am finding MSDN most of the time difficult to understand like many others feel.

So could someone please tell me what the statements above actually mean and also the protocol support for various security.

Comment: I believe the second one should read "Message security is available on all the bindings except for netNamedPipeBinding".

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Could be, but as I am a newbie, I am unsure. If what you say is correct, the MSDN which everyone trust in the world, should have to be careful in their articles. I have found such issues in other articles also where the topic was quite familiar to me. However, I am new to WCF security and stuffs. For instance, a beginner like me definitely get disappointed. And what to trust on if not MSDN :( Well I should do more research on various other articles to understand what "exact" protocl options are available for securities

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if all documentation was perfect and without error.  But, they're written by humans and not without error.  elsewhere like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521301-02-10.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649229.aspx detail the security options bindings more correctly.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: And this is another problem with MSDN that, they have so much of different blogs on same topic, with different contents. And even its not properly managed that, some blogs have older versions still, though I understand its for supporting existing apps, but it has no detail that it will not support latest. Those kind of many observations with MSDN which can be improved.

Comment: I've notified some folks at MS about the conflicts.  I'll post back when it gets fixed.

Comment: I just got word back that the page has been corrected. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx#MessageSecurityWCF  It now states "Message security is available on all of the bindings except for netNamedPipeBinding"

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Thank you so much for taking time to help me understand the concept correctly and also for letting MS know the correction and acknowledging it back. I appreciate it greatly :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The page in question has been corrected to correctly say "Message security is available on all of the bindings except for netNamedPipeBinding"